# Getting a positional slice using a Range variable as a subscript

Tags: raku

```
my @numbers =  <4 8 15 16 23 42>;
```

this works:

```
.say for @numbers[0..2]
# 4
# 8
# 15
```

but this doesn't:

```
my $range = 0..2;
.say for @numbers[$range];
# 16
```

the subscript seems to be interpreting `$range` as the number of elements in the range (3). what gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working as intended. Flatten the range object into a list with [`@numbers[|$range]`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/$VERTICAL_LINE#language_documentation_Operators) or use binding on Range objects to hand them around. https://docs.perl6.org will be updated shortly.

```
On Fri Jul 22 15:34:02 2016, gfldex wrote:
> my @numbers =  <4 8 15 16 23 42>; my $range = 0..2; .say for
> @numbers[$range];
> # OUTPUT«16␤»
> # expected:
> # OUTPUT«4␤8␤15␤»
>
This is correct, and part of the "Scalar container implies item" rule.
Changing it would break things like the second evaluation here:

> my @x = 1..10; my @y := 1..3; @x[@y]
(2 3 4)
> @x[item @y]
4

Noting that since a range can bind to @y in a signature, then Range being a 
special case would make an expression like @x[$(@arr-param)]
unpredictable in its semantics.

> # also binding to $range provides the expected result
> my @numbers =  <4 8 15 16 23 42>; my $range := 0..2; .say for
> @numbers[$range];
> # OUTPUT«4␤8␤15␤»
> y

This is also expected, since with binding there is no Scalar container to
enforce treatment as an item.

So, all here is working as designed.
```

Comment: changed the accepted answer and also deleted my own irrelvant answer

Comment: @beasy Thanks. :) I'm curious if you feel my answer is relevant and adds value to this one?

Comment: yeah definitely, thx. my perspective is that I'm coming at this from the perspective of Perl5 references. although in P5 I would have just said `@numbers[0..2]`

Comment: ok... references in P6 are more similar to P5 than I first thought. in my example you could deref `$numbers` just like in P5, with a little syntax change, by saying `@($numbers)`. https://docs.perl6.org/language/5to6-nutshell.html#Dereferencing

Comment: D'oh. Classic timtowtdi. So `numbers[@$range]` would also work and is probably both clearer and more idiomatic now I think about it. I'll add that to my answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

## A symbol bound to a [Scalar container](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Scalar) yields one thing

Options for getting what you want include:

- Prefix with `@` to get a plural view of the single thing: `numbers[@$range]`; OR
- declare the range variable differently so it works directly

For the latter option, consider the following:

```
# Bind the symbol `numbers` to the value 1..10:
my \numbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

# Bind the symbol `rangeA` to the value 1..10:
my \rangeA  := 1..10;
# Bind the symbol `rangeB` to the value 1..10:
my \rangeB   = 1..10;

# Bind the symbol `$rangeC` to the value 1..10:
my $rangeC  := 1..10;

# Bind the symbol `$rangeD` to a Scalar container
# and then store the value 1..10 in it:`
my $rangeD   = 1..10;

# Bind the symbol `@rangeE` to the value 1..10:
my @rangeE  := 1..10;

# Bind the symbol `@rangeF` to an Array container and then
# store 1 thru 10 in the Scalar containers 1 thru 10 inside the Array
my @rangeF   = 1..10;

say numbers[rangeA];  # (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
say numbers[rangeB];  # (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
say numbers[$rangeC]; # (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
say numbers[$rangeD]; # 10
say numbers[@rangeE]; # (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
say numbers[@rangeF]; # (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
```

A symbol that's bound to a Scalar container (`$rangeD`) always yields a single value. In a `[...]` subscript that single value must be a number. And a range, treated as a single number, yields the length of that range.